# Variables in Schedule class losing values

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, global-variables

I have a schedule class that class a batch class passing the source and target to merge child records from source to target.

Below is the schedule class.

```
global class FIMCConsolidationSchedule  implements schedulable{
    global String source{get;set;}
    global String target{get;set;}

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        try{
            if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
                loadInputs();
            }
            system.debug('source:'+source+'/n'+'target'+target); // here its returning null values
            system.debug('Before the null check if ');
            // make sure the source and target exists
            if(String.isNotBlank(source) && String.isNotBlank(target)){
                system.debug('In the null check if ');
                List<Id> sourceLst = new List<Id>();
                Set<Id> sourceSet = new Set<Id>();
                system.debug('source:'+source+'/n'+'target'+target);
                sourceLst = source.split(',');
                for(Id s :sourceLst ){
                    sourceSet.add(s);
                }
                if(sourceSet.size()>0 &&  String.isNotBlank(target)){
                    FIMCBatchConsolidation consolidatedBatch = new FIMCBatchConsolidation(sourceSet,target);
                    Database.executeBatch(consolidatedBatch,2000);
                }
            }
            system.debug('After the null check if ');
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            GenericErrorHandlerUtil.sendErrorLogs('Exception in FIMCConsolidationSchedule',' Exception Message:'+ e.getMessage() +'\n' +'Stack Trace:'+e.getStackTraceString());      
        }
    }
    global void loadInputs(){
        Map<String,FIMC_Consolidation__mdt> consMDMap = new Map<String,FIMC_Consolidation__mdt>();
        consMDMap = getDefaults(consMDMap); // get the custom metadata types
        String source = '';
        String target = '';
        system.debug('consMDMap.keySet().size()'+consMDMap.keySet().size());

        if(consMDMap.keySet().size()>0){
            for(String s:consMDMap.keySet() ){
                source = consMDMap.get(s).Comma_Separated_Source__c; // debug log shows values here
                target = consMDMap.get(s).Target__c;// debug log shows values here
            }
        }
    }
    // get the custom metadata types
    global Map<String,FIMC_Consolidation__mdt> getDefaults(Map<String,FIMC_Consolidation__mdt> consMDMap){
        List<FIMC_Consolidation__mdt> consLst = new List<FIMC_Consolidation__mdt>();
        consLst = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName, MasterLabel, Language, NamespacePrefix, QualifiedApiName, Target__c, Label, Comma_Separated_Source__c FROM FIMC_Consolidation__mdt where DeveloperName = 'Consolidation' ];
        for(FIMC_Consolidation__mdt mdt : consLst){
            consMDMap.put(mdt.DeveloperName, mdt);
        }
        return consMDMap;
    }
}
```

**Issue:** The source and target variables are set in the loadInputs() method and the debug logs shows the values. But the strings are returning null values after the if(!Test.isRunningTest()) condition. Not sure why the variables are loosing the values. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Seems you are using same variable name for local and class variable?

Comment: @JayantDas thanks for pointing out. This is silly. Just need a fresh pair of eyes. Instead of setting empty string I accidentally created a local var!!! Terrible

Comment: *Am I missing something simple?* -- indeed, you were :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you want to use the class variable in your `exceute()` method.

```
global String source{get;set;}
global String target{get;set;}
```

and that you are populating these values in your `loadInputs()` locally.

```
String source = '';
String target = '';
```

Change the implementation in your `loadInputs()` method to populate the class variables, and that should work.

Reference from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm):

> If a local variable has the same name as a class, the local variable hides methods and variables on the class of the same name